# TOC: Distance between title and text

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

### Original Question

In `scrreprt` the distance between title and content of a TOC is larger than the distance between a regular chapter title and the text body. Does this make sense in terms of typography? And—if not—how can I prevent this from happening?

Thank you!

### Minimal Example

[image: Rendering of the minimal example]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

### Edit 1

Well, okay ... I should have looked a bit harder before posting this. According to the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35267/same-distance-between-chapter-head-and-text-toc), all I need to add is:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip -1.0em}
```

But still: Would you go with the extra vertical space, or would you try to even things out?

Comment: Whether you should do it or not is just a matter of opinion. Probably I'd do it. Just place `\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-1em}}}` to your preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @egreg! Your suggestion works perfectly well for the minimal example above. The glue mentioned in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35269/47061) seems to mess things up again for a multi-page TOC ...