# Is it possible to see the exact measurements LaTeX is working with?

Tags: spacing

This started from a specific question (see below), but now I'm wondering more generally: is there a way to view the exact measurements LaTeX is working with? That is: how much space is there in the margins, home much whitespace left before text begins on page 2 or page 3 and so on?

The specific issue: I'm trying to get all the headings for a book to look identical: chapter headings were no problem, but it took some tweaking to get the bibliography and ToC headings just the same (briefly: a bold all-caps heading and an `\hrule` below that).

For reasons that weren't clear to me, the chapter heading for the table-of-contents page started higher on the page than all the other chapter headings. After some searching here, I've made a few tweaks and the chapter heading is now, to my eye, *almost* identical to the others, but not quite. I'd like to fix that, but trying to track vertical heights by eye has raised this bigger question: is there a programmatic way to see the exact spacing between sections?

Here's a photo with the specific spacing I'm trying to track marked by arrows:

[image].

Here's what it looks like without my kludgy fixes. I'll file a separate question about that shortly:

[image]

Here's the MWE:

```
% [[- LaTeX prelude
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titles}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[extramarks]{titleps}
\newcounter{firstLine}
\setcounter{firstLine}{1}
\newmarkset{firstLine}
\newextramark*{firstLine}{firstLine}
\newcommand*\topfirstLine{\topextramarks{firstLine}{\arabic{firstLine}}}
\newcommand*\botfirstLine{\botextramarks{firstLine}{\arabic{firstLine}}}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\itshape}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\centering\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[\bigskip\hrule]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt}
\newpagestyle{toc}{%
 \sethead[]% even-left
   [CONTENTS]% even-center
   []% even-right
   {}% odd-left
   {CONTENTS}% odd-center
   {}% odd-right
 \setfoot{}%left
  {\thepage}%center
  {}%right
}
\newpagestyle{introduction}{%
 \sethead[]% even-left
   [INTRODUCTION: \sectiontitle]% even-center
   []% even-right
   {}% odd-left
   {INTRODUCTION: \sectiontitle}% odd-center
   {}% odd-right
 \setfoot{}%left
  {\thepage}%center
  {}%right
}
\newpagestyle{text}{%
 \sethead[]% even-left
   [ODYSSEY BOOK 1]% even-center
   []% even-right
   {}% odd-left
   {ODYSSEY BOOK 1}% odd-center
   {}% odd-right
 \setfoot{}%left
  {\thepage}%center
  {}%right
}
\newpagestyle{commentary}{%
 \sethead[]% even-left
   [COMMENTARY:~%
    \edef\tempa{\topfirstLine}\edef\tempb{\botfirstLine}%
    \topfirstLine\ifx\tempa\tempb\relax\else--\botfirstLine\fi]% even-center
   []% even-right
   {}% odd-left
   {COMMENTARY:~%
    \edef\tempa{\topfirstLine}\edef\tempb{\botfirstLine}%
    \topfirstLine\ifx\tempa\tempb\relax\else--\botfirstLine\fi}% odd-center
   {}% odd-right
 \setfoot{}%left
  {\thepage}%center
  {}%right
}
\newpagestyle{bibliography}{%
 \sethead[]% even-left
   [\toptitlemarks{BIBLIOGRAPHY}]% even-center
   []% even-right
   {}% odd-left
   {\toptitlemarks{BIBLIOGRAPHY}}% odd-center
   {}% odd-right
 \setfoot{}%left
  {\thepage}%center
  {}%right
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% -]]

% [[- Document-
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\huge Homer's \textit{Odyssey} Book 1
\vskip2in
\newpage
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\pagestyle{toc}
% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35269/29387 for the \vskip
% Briefly: makes distance between chapter head and text same as for toc title
% and text.
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip -1.0em}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Don't show subsections in the TOC
% \bigskip here keeps the whitespace above toc title and chapters identical
\renewcommand\contentsname{\bigskip C\,O\,N\,T\,E\,N\,T\,S}
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{introduction}
\chapter{I\,N\,T\,R\,O\,D\,U\,C\,T\,I\,O\,N}
\lipsum[1]

\pagestyle{text}
\chapter{O\,D\,Y\,S\,S\,E\,Y\,\ B\,O\,O\,K\ 1}
\lipsum[2]

\pagestyle{commentary}
\chapter{C\,O\,M\,M\,E\,N\,T\,A\,R\,Y}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
% -]]
```

Comment: To space letters use `microtype` and `\textls{..}` or `soul` package and `\so{..}`.

Comment: @Manuel Ah, thank you. I found `T\,H\,I\,S` technique in an older LaTeX document. Is it just outdated? Or was it always wrong?

Comment: @Manuel Actually, it looks like I can't use `microtype` (doesn't work with xelatex yet, and `soul` + `\so` is barfing up on me. So I may still to the other method for now.

Comment: Manual spacing is almost always wrong. You better let TeX work for you than space things yourself. In case you use `fontspec` (I didn't saw it before), you can do something like `\setmainfont{..}[SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=7}]`. Or `\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=7}` wherever you want (in case you don't want all the small caps of the document spaced up).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example has lots of strange markup. I removed the `\,` (letterspacing should be applied elsewhere) and all the page styles (why change pagestyle each chapter???).  I then added `\showoutput` so that TeX leaves a representation of the page in the log file.

```
% [[- LaTeX prelude
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titles}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[extramarks]{titleps}
\newcounter{firstLine}
\setcounter{firstLine}{1}
\newmarkset{firstLine}
\newextramark*{firstLine}{firstLine}
\newcommand*\topfirstLine{\topextramarks{firstLine}{\arabic{firstLine}}}
\newcommand*\botfirstLine{\botextramarks{firstLine}{\arabic{firstLine}}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\centering\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[\bigskip\hrule]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% a new page style for each chapter????
\showoutput
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\huge Homer's \textit{Odyssey} Book 1
\vskip2in
\newpage
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Don't show subsections in the TOC
% \bigskip here keeps the whitespace above toc title and chapters identical
\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[1]


\chapter{ODYSSEY  BOOK 1}
\lipsum[2]


\chapter{COMMENTARY}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Looking at the log you see this for the table of contents page:

```
...\vbox(541.40024+0.0)x360.0, glue set 452.1889fil
....\write-{}
....\pdfdest name{chapter*.1} xyz
....\glue(\topskip) 11.0
....\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
....\penalty 10000
....\glue -50.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 4.20004
....\hbox(9.79996+4.20004)x360.0, glue set 141.93057fil
.....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\rule(9.79996+4.20004)x0.0
.....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/12 C
.....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/12 O
```

so the space from the top of the page to a baseline above the heading is

11pt -50pt +0pt + (0pt plus 1pt)

which is OK although it would be better not to have that stretchable parskip glue there, similarly it would be better to not have the stretchable `\bigskip` glue between the title and the rule, as these spaces can stretch depending on other items on the page, so make the position of the headings inconsistent.

But on the next page above `INTRODUCTION` you see

```
...\vbox(541.40024+0.0)x360.0, glue set 346.42981fil
....\write-{}
....\pdfdest name{chapter.1} xyz
....\write3{\protect \BOOKMARK [0][-]{chapter.1}{INTRODUCTION}{}% 1}
....\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {chapter}{\protect \numberl
ine \ETC.}
....\mark{{\protect \MakeUppercase  {CONTENTS}}{\protect \MakeUppercase  {Chapt
\ETC.}
....\write1{\@writefile{lof}{\protect \addvspace {10\p@ }}}
....\write1{\@writefile{lot}{\protect \addvspace {10\p@ }}}
....\glue(\topskip) 11.0
....\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
....\penalty 10000
....\glue -50.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 4.20004
....\hbox(9.79996+4.20004)x360.0, glue set 180.0fil
.....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\rule(9.79996+4.20004)x0.0
.....\rule(9.79996+4.20004)x0.0
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\penalty 10000
....\glue 0.0
....\glue 0.0
....\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
....\hbox(9.79996+4.20004)x360.0, glue set 124.80556fil
.....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\rule(9.79996+4.20004)x0.0
.....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/12 I
.....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/12 N
```

where you see a whole extra chunk above the title:

```
....\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 4.20004
....\hbox(9.79996+4.20004)x360.0, glue set 180.0fil
.....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\rule(9.79996+4.20004)x0.0
.....\rule(9.79996+4.20004)x0.0
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

so INTRODUCTION is lower than CONTENTS because there is a paragraph above it, so you have an extra `\parskip` and the extra `\baselineskip` from the one line paragraph. The paragraph looks like vertical white space as there is nothing in it other than

```
....\hbox(9.79996+4.20004)x360.0, glue set 180.0fil
.....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\rule(9.79996+4.20004)x0.0
.....\rule(9.79996+4.20004)x0.0
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

which is a centred line (stretch `leftskip`  and `rightskip` with two struts (zero width rules) and zero parfillskip.

This appears to be a "feature" of one of the title packages you are using.

Adding `*` to introduction shows that it is not directly related to table of contents, unnumbered headings are set a line (paragraph) higher than numbered headings.

```
% [[- LaTeX prelude
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{titles}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[extramarks]{titleps}
\newcounter{firstLine}
\setcounter{firstLine}{1}
%\newmarkset{firstLine}
%\newextramark*{firstLine}{firstLine}
%\newcommand*\topfirstLine{\topextramarks{firstLine}{\arabic{firstLine}}}
%\newcommand*\botfirstLine{\botextramarks{firstLine}{\arabic{firstLine}}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\centering\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[\bigskip\hrule]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% a new page style for each chapter????
%\showoutput
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\huge Homer's \textit{Odyssey} Book 1
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Don't show subsections in the TOC
% \bigskip here keeps the whitespace above toc title and chapters identical
\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter*{INTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[1]


\chapter{ODYSSEY  BOOK 1}
\lipsum[2]


\chapter{COMMENTARY}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips in general and `\showoutput` is just what I figured LaTeX must provide.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying `[display]` which typesets the label of the chapter in a separate paragraph. However, you are also specifying an empty label. So you get an empty paragraph for each `\chapter`. Since unnumbered chapters don't get labels anyway, there is no such paragraph in those cases. If you do not want numbered chapters, you should use `\chapter*`. Or, if, for some reason, you want numbers only in the ToC and running heads, at least pick a section shape which doesn't put the empty label in a paragraph of its own.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this was the answer to my originating question of why things weren't lining up. If I use `\chapter*` and remove all my kludges, then the chapters and the ToC line up. But the bibliography no longer does. A better solution, as @DavidCarlisle suggested in chat, is to redefine some of book.cls, rather than keep adding ugly kludges. Thanks!

Comment: @Telemachus If you had linked to your originating question, it would have saved typing! But you are definitely using a witches' brew of formatting approaches, I agree. Note that you should not load `titleps` separately if using `titlesec`. You need to pass the `pagestyles` option to the package instead. (Doesn't cause the problems here but presumably will likely cause others.)

Comment: "Witches' brew" is a good way to put it. Partly because of this thread, I'm going to remove near all of the fancy formatting and start clean. Thanks for the extra info about `titleps` and `titlesec`.